# How/Where is onCreated called in Android

Tags: android, callback, android-source

Doc of

```
void android.app.Activity.onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
says onCreate() is called when the activity is starting.

So how and where onCreate() is called and who calls it? I searched in Android source code and didn't find any code which called onCreate() with value of savedInstanceState.

Comment: I assume you mean "onCreate" and not "onCreated" - (i.e. no "d")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found out the answer by examining stack trace of onCreate like bellow:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        throw new Exception("MY_EXCEPTION");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Stack trace:

```
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667): java.lang.Exception: MY_EXCEPTION
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at com.example.mybrowser.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5246)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
10-10 10:10:34.139: W/System.err(10667):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-10 10:10:34.179: W/IntentResolver(1097): resolveIntent: multiple matches, only some with CATEGORY_DEFAULT
10-10 10:10:34.189: W/ContextImpl(10682): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1511 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:494 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:2410
```

So, the ANSWER:
onCreate is called by android.app.Activity.performCreate, and performCreate is called by android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate, ...
for example:

```
final void performCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    onCreate(icicle);
    mVisibleFromClient = !mWindow.getWindowStyle().getBoolean(
            com.android.internal.R.styleable.Window_windowNoDisplay, false);
    mFragments.dispatchActivityCreated();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The top of the Android doc you listed says that "'onCreate' is called to initialize an activity"... different than what you stated in your question. It is not  necessarily called when  the activity  is started. You must initialized an activity  before it actually starts. And placement, I've seen onCreate at the bottom of code, but I believe you are talking about in the stack calls. Try to be clear in question. Hope I helped. There is plenty of into on that site, this site, and android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Search "when the activity is starting" at the doc, and you'll find my description is right. onCreate is always called; but it's not necessary to be overriden. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I can't comment on your answer, due to rep < 50, but you should mark your answer as correct to close.